# numpy suddenly stopped working on Raspberry

Tags: python, numpy, pip, installation

Week before perfectly working `numpy` stopped working under **Python 3.7** on **Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)**. Still works with **Python 2.7**.

```
~ $ python3
Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr  3 2019, 05:39:12)
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py", line 7, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
ImportError: libf77blas.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError:

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy c-extensions failed.
- Try uninstalling and reinstalling numpy.
- If you have already done that, then:
  1. Check that you expected to use Python3.7 from "/usr/bin/python3",
     and that you have no directories in your PATH or PYTHONPATH that can
     interfere with the Python and numpy version "1.18.1" you're trying to use.
  2. If (1) looks fine, you can open a new issue at
     https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues.  Please include details on:
     - how you installed Python
     - how you installed numpy
     - your operating system
     - whether or not you have multiple versions of Python installed
     - if you built from source, your compiler versions and ideally a build log

- If you're working with a numpy git repository, try `git clean -xdf`
  (removes all files not under version control) and rebuild numpy.

Note: this error has many possible causes, so please don't comment on
an existing issue about this - open a new one instead.

Original error was: libf77blas.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Tried to reinstall:

```
~ $ sudo pip3 uninstall -y numpy
Uninstalling numpy-1.18.1:
  Successfully uninstalled numpy-1.18.1
~ $ sudo pip3 install numpy
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting numpy
  Using cached https://www.piwheels.org/simple/numpy/numpy-1.18.1-cp37-cp37m-linux_armv7l.whl
Installing collected packages: numpy
Successfully installed numpy-1.18.1
```

Did not work.

Tried first reinstalling `setuptools` using `sudo pip3 uninstall -y setuptools`, returns:

```
Not uninstalling setuptools at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, outside environment /usr
Can't uninstall 'setuptools'. No files were found to uninstall.
```

But when I try to install it using `sudo pip3 install setuptools`, returns:

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (40.8.0)
```

I am confused, do not know what to do.

Comment: Have you checked PATH as written in error massage 1. ?

Comment: `numpy` is located in `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/`, where pip installs packages by default. `python3` I am using is located in `/usr/bin/`.
But I do not think that I understood how to check it. Could you tell me a bit more how shall I do it?

Comment: I'm not sure but... tyr $PATH and check path /usr/local/lib is there for numpy (I have met the case /user/local was not set by default). Or [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/747408/do-python3-and-python-use-different-path-variables) might help, install python3-numpy.

Comment: `apt install libatlas-base-dev`

Comment: @hoefling, Hallo! Seems like it is a dependency for `numpy`. Problem solved! Danke Dir!